# MySQL add date in command that not working for me

Tags: mysql

1.find all sales done in september 
2.the saldate format is year/month/date missing the last line in my command?

```
select s.orderno "order number",sa.saledate "sale date", st.lastname "last 
name"
from sales s, sales sa, staff st
where s.orderno = sa.orderno and
sa.staffno = st.staffno and
sa.saledate = ????????;
```

Comment: your code seems weird. 1. Are you trying to return s.orderno as "order number" or is "order number just a string"(same goes to others)? 2. You're joining 3 tables without JOIN commands, is that even allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql functions **MONTH** to find the month of a particular date and **STR_TO_DATE** to parse a string to a date:

```
select s.orderno ,sa.saledate , st.lastname 
from sales s, sales sa, staff st
where s.orderno = sa.orderno and
sa.staffno = st.staffno and
MONTH(sa.saledate) = 9
```

MONTH: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php

STR_TO_DATE: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php

Comment: thanks , but i need to give any sale date that happend in month 09 and dosent matter what year or date

Comment: Oh, that's easier, just do `MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(sa.saledate,'yyyy/mm/dd')) = 9`

Comment: mysql> select s.orderno "order number",sa.saledate "sale date", st.lastname "las
t name"
    -> from sales s, sales sa, staff st
    -> where s.orderno = sa.orderno and
    -> sa.staffno = st.staffno;
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| order number | sale date  | last name |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 020002       | 2014-09-21 | McLester  |
| 020003       | 2014-09-21 | Thomas    |
| 020004       | 2014-09-21 | Rolfes    |
| 020005       | 2014-09-21 | Zambini   |
| 020006       | 2014-09-21 | Charles   |
| 020007       | 2014-09-22 | Roddick   |

Comment: your field is already a date not a string, so you just need to do: `MONTH(sa.saledate) = 9`

Comment: thanks perfect , i need your help to fix my class project can you help me?